# How can I make my button click show an ImageView that corresponds with my randomized TextView?

Tags: java, android, arrays

Right now I have the code where if a user clicks the button, it will show a random string from my array.
I am trying to make it where when a user clicks the button, it will show also show an `ImageView` that corresponds with the string.

For example, if the string pulled is "movies", it will show a movie clipart in the `ImageView`. I have the clipart jpgs in my drawables, and this is my XML file where I had my string array, I added the drawables to this, unsure if that was the right thing to do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name ="activityArray">
        <item>Music</item>
        <item>Movie</item>
        <item>Board Games</item>
        <item>Video Games</item>
        <item>Guitar</item>
    </string-array>

    <array name="activityImg">
        <item>@drawable/music</item>
        <item>@drawable/movie</item>
        <item>@drawable/boardgames</item>
        <item>@drawable/videogames</item>
        <item>@drawable/guitar</item>



</array>
</resources>
```

And this is my MainActivity.

```
package com.example.cjada.activit;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView; 
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

            String[] activities = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.activityArray);


            Random random = new Random();

            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            TextView buttonResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.buttonResult);
                buttonResult.setText(activities[random.nextInt(activities.length -1)]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your not using the imageView in you code, and as it's easier if we use create an image resource array in the activity and then retrieve the random index:

```
int[] images = {R.drawable.music, R.drawable.movie, R.drawable.boardgames, R.drawable.viewgames, R.drawable.guitar};
```

in the onClick:

```
String[] activities = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.activityArray);

Random random = new Random();
int rand = random.nextInt(activities.length -1);

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

TextView buttonResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.buttonResult);

buttonResult.setText(activities[rand]);
imageView.setImageResource(images[rand]);
```

Comment: Alright, so with your code I am able to get both the imageview and the text to be randomized, is there a way to get them to match? Right now both are random, but they aren't matching up i.e. movie clip art when the text "movie" is shown

Comment: they should be the same, as im using a variable rand to match both the  random image and text. can you share your full code?